# QGIS One Shapefile, Two attribute colums, both need to be styled in dependence of each other

Tags: qgis, shapefile, style, fields-attributes

I didn´t find an easy solution for my problem. 
Im working with QGIS and i got one shapefile but i want to implement two atributes together.

1. I need to make a bubble with different sizes based on attribute column 1 (Values 0-2) and
2. the color in the bubble Should to be adjusted based on attribute column 2 (Values from 0 - 50, 5 colors (0-10=red, 10-20=yellow, etc.).

The color in the bubble should fill out the whole bubble. Can you help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a Graduated style to control the colors of your symbols (as usual) then to control the size of the bubbles you can click on the Symbol -> Change... button and set the size value to an expression.

[image]

Comment: Thanks, but this is not helping me, i need to auto-include the sizes from annother column. I don´t want to adjust everything manually...

Comment: that's what the expression is for it controls the size of all the bubbles based on an attribute

Comment: i got it now! it works!! Super awesome, thanks for your help!